# Azure Batch microtask parallel processing (Modify Task Queue)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-batch

I am trying to parallelise micro-tasks that will be fired off on one of the VMs and should get parallelised on all the VMs. How can I modify the Azure Batch queue. Is there any way to add a task to the queue through the API?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to add a task to the queue through the API?

If you use Azure Batch .NET Library, you could add a task to a job using following code.

```
private static async Task<List<CloudTask>> AddTasksAsync(
    BatchClient batchClient,
    string jobId,
    string taskId,
    List<ResourceFile> inputFiles,
    string taskCommand)
{
    // Create a collection to hold the tasks that we'll be adding to the job
    List<CloudTask> tasks = new List<CloudTask>();

    CloudTask task = new CloudTask(taskId, taskCommand);
    task.ResourceFiles = inputFiles;
    tasks.Add(task);

    await batchClient.JobOperations.AddTaskAsync(jobId, tasks);

    return tasks;
}
```

If you want to use REST API, link below is for your reference.

[Add a task to a job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/add-a-task-to-a-job)

If you encounter any problem when using the APIs above, please feel free to let me know.